# Failed to resolve: com.github.kimchangyoun:rootbeerFresh: Affected Modules: app, service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

api 'org.connectbot.jbcrypt:jbcrypt:1.0.0'
//api 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'

```
// root detect
api 'com.github.kimchangyoun:rootbeerFresh:'

//api 'com.github.hussainderry:secure-preferences:4.0.0'

api project(':style')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use this library to check root use this in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation 'kimchangyoun:rootbeerFresh-lib:0.0.10'
}
```

visit this for more info: https://github.com/KimChangYoun/rootbeerFresh